# iOS SwiftUI - use NavigationLink and perform additional action

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

```
            NavigationLink(destination: ShowWebView(showWhat: "privacy"), label: {
                HStack(spacing: 32) {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "info.square")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .frame(width: 26)
                    
                    Text("privacy_policy")
                    
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            })
```

I need to perform additional action when opening ShowWebView.

This is what I've tried:

```
            NavigationLink(destination: ShowWebView(showWhat: "privacy"), label: {
                HStack(spacing: 32) {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "info.square")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .frame(width: 26)
                    
                    Text("privacy_policy")
                    
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(){
                        self.offsetMenu = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
                    }
                }
            })
```

but this way only what's inside onTapGesture is performed but the view ShowWebView doesn't get opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the variable applying the `.onAppear` modifier to `ShowWebView`.

This is the code to obtain what you are looking for:

```
NavigationLink {
    ShowWebView(showWhat: "privacy")

        // Add this modifier
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation {
                self.offsetMenu = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            }
        }
    
} label: {
    HStack(spacing: 32) {
        
        Image(systemName: "info.square")
            .font(.title2)
            .frame(width: 26)
        
        Text("privacy_policy")
        
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
}
```